# Add a Hyperlink to a Trello card

Tags: trello, links

I have recently been exploring the new web application Trello and I want to add hyperlinks to a card.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like Stack Exchange, Trello allows [MarkDown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) in card descriptions, so you can put links into them using this type of syntax:

```
Click [here](http://www.whatever.com) to go to the page.
```

Which will give

Click [here](http://www.whatever.com) to go to the page.

Answer (score 10):

To clarify, Trello allows [MarkDown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) in the description field of a card.  You can use a markdown formatted link (`[Google](http://www.google.com)`), or you can just type put a URL (like `http://www.google.com`) and it will be converted to a link

Card comments don't allow markdown, but they can also contain URLs, which will be converted to links.  Some URLs (like ones for youtube) will be converted to previews using [embed.ly](http://embed.ly/)

[image: An example of the different kinds of links]

Comment: Just a note that there can't be a space between the last square bracket and the opening parenthesis - this tripped me up.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up creating a small extension called [GTD: Trello Card Links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gtd-trello-card-links/kpbpniempdinfjfgphomcfkijinlgfgj) that allows you to put any link on the front of your Trello Cards and make it clickable. I always found it really annoying having to click on the back of cards to get to where I wanted to be!

**Features**

- Clickable Links on cards
- Multiple Links on cards
- Link to cards and create EPIC stories

[image]

**Installation Process**

1. Install extension
2. Navigate to your Trello Board
3. Create new Trello Card
4. Paste a link
5. Click the link!

---

**Related Resources**

- Chrome Extension: https://goo.gl/18FFjb
- Demo: https://trello.com/b/6DoBxhuZ/gtd-trello-card-links
- Github (opensource): https://github.com/oneezy/gtd-trello-card-links
- Patreon: https://www.patreon.com/oneezy

Comment: Nice idea, Would you consider expanding so a preview is given (e.g. like in whatsapp)

Comment: Do  you mean something like this where it displays the thumbnail and other meta data? http://cdn.gsmarena.com/imgroot/news/15/11/whatsapp-links/-728/gsmarena_001.jpg

Comment: Yea, exactly that!!

Comment: That would definitely be a cool feature! I'll look into it

Comment: Thanks for putting the code on Github. Really helpful to see the implementation :)

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Another way to add link to your text is to use [footnote markdown syntax](https://help.ghost.org/hc/en-us/articles/224410728-Markdown-Guide#footnotes) - especially when the URL is very long and makes your content ugly i.e. hard to read under raw view.

```
Some text [your text with linked]
[your text with linked]: https://www.your-link.com
```

### Sample

The normal way for hyperlink markdown e.g.
[trello link markdown](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=trello+link+markdown&oq=trello+link+mark&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j69i64.4096j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) which makes this text ugly.

```
The normal way for hyperlink markdown e.g. [trello link markdown](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=trello+link+markdown&oq=trello+link+mark&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j69i64.4096j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
which makes this text ugly i.e. hard to read under raw view.
```

The footnote way to add link e.g. [trello link markdown](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=trello+link+markdown&oq=trello+link+mark&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j69i64.4096j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) which keeps this text clean and clear in raw view

```
The footnote way to add link e.g. [trello link markdown] which keeps this text clean and clear in raw view
[trello link markdown]: https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=trello+link+markdown&oq=trello+link+mark&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j69i64.4096j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
```

Answer (score -1):

Trello does support [markdown hyperlink in card's comment](https://trello.com/c/OKVduwHL/1096-markdown-in-card-comments), now.

*Example*: Click [here](http://www.whatever.com) to go to the page. (thanks @ben-k)

Comment: How would you add this? Can you give an example?

Comment: Come on! Are you serious about this? Have you read the whole discussion?  
_________________________________________________________________________________________
1. Markdown is markdown. I just stated that it was now supported in card's comment as it was in other Trello parts  
2. Two previous answers (@ben-k and @daniel-lecheminant) were given with the syntax for markdown hyperlinks  3. It's even described when you fill a comment in SE!!