# How do you add a hyperlink to a Trello card title?

Tags: trello, links

I'm in the process of migrating my productivity list from a Google Doc to Trello because I really like the workflow concept that Trello enables users to use.

The trouble I'm having right now though is finding a good way to use a card to link to external resources as I have been accustomed to doing in Google Docs. For example, in my productivity list I have a category for things I want to read on performance-oriented CSS, and below the heading is a list of links to articles I've come across.

I know that I could simply copy and paste URLs into a card, but then A) I have to copy and paste them into the browser again (rather than simply clicking on them) to get to the article, and B) I cannot display the title of the article as the text, I'm limited to simply using the entire URL for the title of a card, which seems really cumbersome and counter-intuitive to the advantages of the Trello user interface.

So does anyone know if/how I can accomplish this?

**EDIT:** FTR I did try to use Markdown as suggested in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/18932/20525), but unless I just failed to do it correctly, it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to add links in card titles. Titles don't accept any formatting.

That linked answer is incorrect, and I've submitted an edit. Markdown is only available in card descriptions, not titles or comments.

Comment: Note: I work on the Trello team. FWIW, I think the team is pretty set on adding Markdown support in card comments eventually. As for support in titles, I'm not sure.

Comment: Arbitrary limitations like this are a pain. The link is the description and the title ... why should I have to add another level when it isn't needed? I'm trying out Trello and this has already turned me off of it.

Comment: It would be nice to have links and previews in the title, e.g a link to a ted talk

Comment: This and looks like you can't have description visible on card - wtf

Comment: @BobbyGrace any chance that this is in the plan for the future? I understand that the difficulty is that the title is responsible for opening the card but having at least an option for it to show on the card without opening similar to how pictures show would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Markdown does not work in Card titles because the card title opens the card. Markdown works in Card descriptions.

Paste this text into a card description and save it:

```
\[StackExchange]\(http://webapps.stackexchange.com)
```

You should then see **StackExchange** as a hyperlink in the card description.  Brackets surround the display text, parenthesis surround the URL to use.

If you put that same text line in the title or an activity comment that is what you will see, all the text, brackets etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a small [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/card-title-hyperlinks-trello/) for Firefox that does precisely this if anyone is still having this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the extension João -- how do we use this? (Documentation is light).

Comment: this doesnt seem to work for me eiether

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Trello in Chrome, there is a Chrome Extension, which dies this trick.

This one is it: [GTD: Trello Card Links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gtd-trello-card-links/kpbpniempdinfjfgphomcfkijinlgfgj)

[image]