# Using reference-style hyperlinks in Trello comments

Tags: trello, trello-cards

How can I enter links into a comment on a Trello board using the [reference-style Markdown formatting](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link)?

Of this format:

> Here is [an example] [id] reference-style link.
>
> [id]: http://example.com/

Various places I have looked [including this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18931/add-a-hyperlink-to-a-trello-card), say that Trello comments now support Markdown hyperlinks. However, I can't get the reference-style links to work. The actual references at the bottom becomes a link but the text in the comment doesn't become a link

Comment: I'm thinking the other comments I saw were incorrect. It's hard to tell if this is the latest documentation, but this [How To Format Your Text](http://help.trello.com/article/821-using-markdown-in-trello) help article from Trello would indicate that the reference style link isn't supported.